# HikariCP initialization error

Tags: java, spring-boot, hikaricp

I have a web app i am managing, its a spring boot application using HikariCP withe the following config

```
@Bean(name = "DS")
    public DataSource datasource() throws IOException {
        final HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName(datasourceDriverClassName);
        ds.setJdbcUrl(datasourceUrl);
        ds.setUsername(datasourceUsername);
        ds.setPassword(getSecurePassword());
        ds.setMaximumPoolSize(maxPoolSize);  
        ds.setMetricRegistry(metricRegistry);
        return ds;
    }
```

The problem is that this works fine on my dev machine but when i deploy to some servers, i get

```
com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource                      | HikariCP pool HikariPool-1 is starting. 
2015-08-14 13:22:13,203  INFO | http-nio-7070-exec-5 | com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool                       | HikariCP pool HikariPool-1 is shutting down. 
2015-08-14 13:22:13,203 DEBUG | http-nio-7070-exec-5 | o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver         | Resolving exception from handler [public java.util.List<com.model.Transaction> com.api.TransactionApi.search(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Double,java.util.Date,java.util.Date,int,int) throws com.exceptions.AppServiceException]: com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolInitializationException: Exception during pool initialization 
2015-08-14 13:22:13,203 DEBUG | http-nio-7070-exec-5 | o.s.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory    | Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'apiAdvice' 
         | com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolInitializationException: Exception during pool initialization
```

I have tried connecting to different database servers, on some it works, while it doesn't work for the majority of DB servers i have tried.

DB Server is MS SQLSERVER 2014.

Thanks

Comment: You should fix your logging, those lines you pasted are worthless since they don't show the cause of the exception.

Comment: Additionally, enable debug logging.  Clearly, HikariCP cannot acquire a connection to the DB, better logging will tell you why.